# How to show user information when user name is at the end of link

Tags: php, html, web

I have a website, say its

http://www.mywebsite.com

now I can show the user information if i do something like

http://mywebsite.com/user.php?name=John

i use php to query database to generate user information into an html page

But how can i do it like

http://www.mywbsite.com/john

do i create a page for each and every user i have ? or is there a better way

Comment: You can use apache `mod rewrite` to hide `user.php?name=` if your web server is apache

Comment: You can only have one user John on your site?

Comment: The question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic rule to hide `user.php?name=` from the URL. Put this in your root `.htaccess` file.

`mod_rewrite` must be enabled with PHP and this will work for the PHP version higher than 5.2.6.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

and then for get user

```
<?php 
 $user = $_GET['name'];
?>
```